# Cannot get image to center with css

Tags: center, css

No matter how often and where I apply a margin: 0px auto; even with an !important tag I just can't get the large sample rugs to center.  It's probably something obvious. Any ideas? http://martinezstudio.com/wp_studio/

Comment: Do you know the width of the images? (Or is it non-standard?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`margin: 0px auto;` will only center block elements. Try adding a `display: block;` to your declarations and giving your image specific width.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#simpleslider_show>div{
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally both of these answers would have worked like a charm.  I turned off all plugins and played around more, but no go.  Something buried deep somewhere just doesn't want my images to center.

So, I cheated.  I made all my images the full width and centered on a white background.  They are a bit bigger then they would be if the code made them center, but the stinking things work and look ok.  Thanks for your help!